# Google maps api V3 show nothing, blank page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make map showing to me multiple routes, but for me it just show blank page even the map is not showing. What's the problem in my code, i can't find it. It's just blank page.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        width: 63%;
        height: 100%;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}
        });

        function renderDirections(result) {
          var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          draggable: true,
          map: map,
        });

          directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }


        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        function requestDirections(start, end) {
          directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          }, function(result) {
            renderDirections(result);
          });
        }

        requestDirections('Huntsville, AL', 'Boston, MA');
        requestDirections('Bakersfield, CA', 'Vancouver, BC');

</script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6POCSerSPAK1t9zhKiFbiTDzh5TDPeYg&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to write the callback function in your code :

```
function initMap() {

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}
    });

    function renderDirections(result) {
      var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      draggable: true,
      map: map,
    });

      directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    function requestDirections(start, end) {
      directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(result) {
        renderDirections(result);
      });
    }

    requestDirections('Huntsville, AL', 'Boston, MA');
    requestDirections('Bakersfield, CA', 'Vancouver, BC');
}
```

Because you are calling it in src but you never implement it :

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6POCSerSPAK1t9zhKiFbiTDzh5TDPeYg&callback=initMap"
```